# Show multiple months sales figures in woocommerce report using $wc_report->get_order_report_data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a report of sales per product for the current month which is displaying correctly.

I would like to also display the last 3 months sales too though. Here is my current code:

```
    global $woocommerce, $wpdb, $product;
    include_once($woocommerce->plugin_path() . '/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-admin-report.php');
   
    // WooCommerce Admin Report
    $wc_report = new WC_Admin_Report();
    
    // Set date parameters for the current month
    $start_date = strtotime(date('Y-m', current_time('timestamp')) . '-01 midnight');
    $end_date = strtotime('+1month', $start_date) - 86400;
    $wc_report->start_date = $start_date;
    $wc_report->end_date = $end_date;
    
    // Avoid max join size error
    $wpdb->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');
    // Get data for current month sold products
        $sold_products = $wc_report->get_order_report_data(array(
            'data' => array(
                '_product_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                    'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                    'function' => '',
                    'name' => 'product_id'
                ),
                '_qty' => array(
                    'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                    'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                    'function' => 'SUM',
                    'name' => 'quantity'
                )
            ),
            'query_type' => 'get_results',
            'group_by' => 'product_id',
            'where_meta' => '',
            'order_by' => 'quantity DESC',
            'order_types' => wc_get_order_types('order_count'),
            'filter_range' => TRUE,
            'order_status' => array('completed','processing','on-hold'),
        ));
```

and displaying the data:

```
<div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong><?php _e('Name', 'text-domain') ?></strong></th>
                    <th><strong><?php _e('Current Month', 'text-domain') ?></strong></th>
                    <th><strong><?php _e('Last Month', 'text-domain') ?></strong></th>
                    <th><strong><?php _e('2 Months ago', 'text-domain') ?></strong></th>
                    <th><strong><?php _e('3 Months ago', 'text-domain') ?></strong></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >
                <?php foreach ($sold_products as $product) { ?>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_edit_post_link(intval($product->product_id))); ?>"><strong><?php echo html_entity_decode(get_the_title($product->product_id)); ?></strong></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo intval($product->quantity); ?></td>
                        <td>...last months sales...</td>
                        <td>...2 months ago sales...</td>
                        <td>...3 months ago sales...</td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But how do I query different dates seeing as the start and end date are defined before the loop?